# Reading from collection and updating to another collection in Mongodb database

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to read data from one collection and write a new collection with the updated data in MongoDB database .But not able to create and update the new collection .The issue documents are getting updated but not able to write to the new collection. Can anyone help me please .

private String NextMonth(String system , String period) {

```
     mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(mongoClient, database);
            MongoDatabase database = this.mongoClient.getDatabase(this.database);
            collectionDB = database.getCollection(Sample_TMP);
            
            mergeCollection = database.getCollection("UpdatedCollection");
            {
                Consumer<Document> processBlock = new Consumer<Document>() {
                    int count;
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Document document) {
                        System.out.println(document);
                    }
                };
    
                String nextPeriod = Utilities.calculatePeriodAfter(financialPeriod);
            
    
                List<? extends Bson> pipeline = Arrays.asList(
                        new Document()
                                .append("$match", new Document()
                                        .append("Type.key", "PP")
                                        .append("AmountType.key", "IN")
                                        .append("SystemID.key", sourceSystem)
                                        .append("Period", financialPeriod)
                                ),
                        new Document()
                                .append("$addFields", new Document()
                                        .append("RecordID", "$_id")
                                        .append("Period", nextPeriod)
                                        .append("Period2", nextPeriod)
                                        
                                        )
                                        .append("ClaimFinancialActivity.MonthlyLossOutstandingMovementAmount.amount", new Document()
                                                .append("$multiply", Arrays.asList(
                                                        "$ClaimFinancialActivity.MonthlyLossOutstandingMovementAmount.amount",
                                                         Decimal128.parse("-1.0")
                                                        )
                                                )
                                        )
                                     
                                     
                                        .append("Reserve", true)
                                ),
                        new Document()
                                .append("$project", new Document()
                                        .append("_id", 0.0)
                                        .append("ClosingAmt", 0.0)
                                        .append("UnsignedAmount", 0.0)
                                        .append("Reserve", 0.0)
                                ),
                        new Document()
                                .append("$out", mergeCollection)
                );
                AggregateIterable<Document> resultsPipeline = mergeCollection.aggregate(pipeline).allowDiskUse(false);
                
                List<? extends Bson> pipeline2 = Arrays.asList(
                        new Document()
                                .append("$match", new Document()
                                        .append("key", "SS")
                                        .append("key", "EXO")
                                        .append("key", sourceSystem)
                                        .append("Period", financialPeriod)
                                ),
                        new Document()
                                .append("$addFields", new Document()
                                        .append("RecordID", "$_id")
                                        .append("Period", nextPeriod)
                                        .append("Period", nextPeriod)
                                        
                                        )
                                        .append("amount", new Document()
                                                .append("$multiply", Arrays.asList(
                                                        "$amount",
                                                         Decimal128.parse("-1.0")
                                                        )
                                                )
                                        )
                                       
                                      
                                        .append("Reserve", true)
                                ),
                        new Document()
                                .append("$project", new Document()
                                        .append("_id", 0.0)
                                        .append("ClosingAmt", Decimal128.parse("0.0"))
                                        .append("UnsignedAmount",  Decimal128.parse("0.0"))
                                        .append("Reserve", Decimal128.parse("0.0"))
                                ),
                        new Document()
                                .append("$merge", new Document()
                                        .append("into", mergeCollection)
                                )
                );
    
                AggregateIterable<Document> resultsPipeline2 =  mergeCollection.aggregate(pipeline2)
                        .allowDiskUse(false);
                
                Document deleteQuery = new Document();
                deleteQuery.append("key", "XX");
                deleteQuery.append("SystemID.key", sourceSystem);
                deleteQuery.append("Period", nextPeriod);
                deleteQuery.append("Reserve", true);
                collectionDB.deleteMany(deleteQuery);
                //Update transaction sequence numbers- find query with projection
                BasicDBObject projectFields=new BasicDBObject();
                projectFields.append("_id", "1");
                FindIterable<Document> iterable=mergeCollection.find().projection(projectFields);
                iterable.forEach(new Block<Document>() {
                    @Override
                    public void apply(final Document document) {
                        System.out.println(document);
                    }
                });
    
                // int currentID = 1;
                String systemSplit = sourceSystem.split("-")[0];
                String currentID = String.valueOf(1);
                String newID = systemSplit + "OB" + nextPeriod;
                int leftSpace = 20 - newID.length();
                String paddedID = padToLength(currentID, leftSpace);
                newID = newID + paddedID;
    
                /*update Query*/
                Bson filter = eq("_id", 1);
                BasicDBObject updateTempQuery = new BasicDBObject();
                updateTempQuery.append("$set",
                        new Document()
                                .append("Common.TransactionIdentifier", newID)
                );
                mergeCollection.updateMany(filter,updateTempQuery);
    
                /*merge Query*/
                List<? extends Bson> pipeline3 = Arrays.asList(
                        new Document()
                                .append("$merge", "collectionDB"));
                mergeCollection.aggregate(pipeline3)
                        .allowDiskUse(true)
                        .forEach(processBlock);
                
            }
          
        }
```

Comment: i do not see any new  connection for new collection to write documnent

Comment: MongoDB does not have permissions granularity that stipulates you can insert into a collection but you cannot create a collection.  If a collection does not exist, and you attempt to insert into it, it will first create the collection and then insert into it.

Comment: Database is already created in MongoDB database manually ,when I try to insert the data the collection is showing empty results

Comment: New collection is created like below : String collectionName = "Samplecollection";

            if (!mongoOps.collectionExists(collectionName)) {
                collectionNew = mongoOps.createCollection(collectionName);
                LOG.info("Collection %s was successfully created", collectionName);
            } else {
                collectionNew = mongoOps.getCollection(collectionName);
            }

Comment: Is there any issue with my code as not able to write the aggregate results into the new collection